# Dynamic (Adjustable) font size for Mobile-First design?

Tags: jquery-plugins, responsive-design, font-size

You know there are some jQuery plugins like [FlowType](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) that adjust the font size based on the elements width.

But I believe they don't play well with **mobile-first** designs. Because when the viewport size gets small, the element's width get narrower too. Thus, the font size become too small and hard to read on mobile.

I want the texts to be big on mobile and get smaller when the viewport size get bigger. Is there any solution?

or are there any similar approach that's friendly with a mobile-first design?

Comment: Why not just set the size in your media queries?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Because if we do so, we have to add hundreds of css code to handle font sizes for all elements and adjust them accordingly to each viewport size.